# Why is the show called "Stranger Things" instead of "Strange Things"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrases

Ok, I know this is a dumb question, but since I'm not a native english speaker, I've been wondering about it for a while. haha

I've never seen a sentence using the word Stranger to define things. I did see it to define a person you do not know, but not for things.

So, my question is: In this title, "Stranger Things", does it mean that these things that are happening, are more strange than the "normal" strange? (Does it make sense at all?)

Like, this is strange, but thattt, oh boy, that's STRANGER!

I'll appreciate any help to clarify this stupid question of mine.

Comment: The use is stranger as a comparative. There are strange things, and then there are stranger things.

Comment: "Stranger than fiction" is a common phrase.

Comment: *Why* is something only the show creators would know; captaingabbeh has provided that answer. There is also a play on words; the saying *stranger things have happened* refers to events, whereas the show includes *stranger things* which are very much physical.

Comment: Because they wanted the show to be stranger than all the other shows on TV.

Comment: Another possible reason: "stranger" is of course also a noun referring to an unknown person, so they might have used that to subtly suggest the show being about "strangers", like Eleven

Comment: The phrase "strange things" also has a slightly clumsy rhythm in English, where as "stranger things" flows more smoothly.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently the showmakers picked it because it sounds similar to a Stephen King book called "Needful Things"

https://www.thedailybeast.com/inside-stranger-things-the-duffer-bros-on-how-they-made-the-tv-hit-of-the-summer

(Look for the question "I’m not sure if you guys have ever talked about this before, but how did you settle on the title Stranger Things? I know originally it was Montauk.")

I actually thought it was a play on the English saying "Stranger things have happened", which is something you would say if you were discussing an event that was possible but unlikely. For example, if my friend and I are talking about the weather and my friend suggests it will snow in August, I might say something like "Well, I guess stranger things have happened" to show I don't really think it's going to happen.